# Storing FB id vs. username

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing a facebook login, and would want to store the fb data of the user. I just want to be able to check facebook profiles of users, i thought of storing the fb_id rathen than the fb_username, because I assume the username could be changed. If I store the fb_id, how can I pull up facebook profiles by id

Comment: You can not get username so yes use user ID

Comment: _"If I store the fb_id, how can I pull up facebook profiles by id"_ - request the `link` field from the API as well ...